# How to read/write nested ArrayLists when using Parcelable in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, marshalling

I'm having some trouble parceling a structure like this:

`private ArrayList<ArrayList<SomeObject>> objects;`

Which comes from a JSON with this structure:

```
{
  "a" :[
         [
           {}, {}, {}, {}
         ]
       ]
}
```

My writing to parcel goes like this:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeList(objects);
}

private Listings(Parcel in) {
    this.objects = new ArrayList<ArrayList<SomeObject>>();
    in.readArrayList(SomeObject.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

But when unmarshalling i'm only getting `"a" : []`

Any ideas?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to check.

First, the most obvious is that you do not assign `this.objects` to anything except for an empty list.  You either need to assign the output of your call to `readArrayList()` to `this.objects` or call `readList` with `this.objects` as the first parameter as done below.

Second, make sure `SomeObject` meets the requirements laid out in [`Parcel.writeValue()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29).

Third, if you called `unmarshall` to load the parcel, try adding a call to [`Parcel.setDataPosition(0)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#setDataPosition%28int%29) in your listings method to make sure the parcel is set to read from the beginning before you start parsing. Like so --

```
private Listings(Parcel in) {
    in.setDataPosition(0);
    in.readList(this.object, SomeObject.class.getClassLoader());
}
```